# Flutter Shadow appearing around Divider's line in ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I used ListView.separated to reproduce the Twitter's homepage, with a Divider as separator. My items are white Containers, and it's weird because we see a kind of shadow around the Divider, or like its box. Have you faced this?

Here the divider:
[image]

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:
          SafeArea(
            child:
              ListView.separated(
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return PlaceCard(place: place1);
                  },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Divider(thickness: 0);
                  },
              )
          )
    );
  }
}
```

```
class PlaceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Place place;

  const PlaceCard({Key? key, required this.place}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 400,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: Add some snippet and code as well for better under standing

Comment: try adding `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,` on theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see that is that the height of your `Divider` and `Scaffold` background color. If you set `Scaffold's` background color to white or play with `Divider` height parameter it would disappear. Like this:

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white, // <--- add this
    body: SafeArea(
      ...
    )
)
```

or instead of set `thickness` to `0` set `height` to `0`:

```
Divider(height: 0);
```